# Trouble Establishing Connection Between Python PyQt Socket Server and Client in Same Network

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm currently facing challenges in establishing a connection between two computers on the same network using Python and PyQt's socket classes. While I've successfully implemented a server-client setup with Python's built-in socket library, my attempt to do the same with PyQt's socket classes is failing.

server.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpServer, QHostAddress

IP = '192.168.6.66'

class Server(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.server = QTcpServer(self)
        self.server.listen(QHostAddress(IP), 12345)
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.handle_client_connection)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)

        self.message_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.message_input.setGeometry(10, 220, 200, 30)

        self.send_button = QPushButton("Send Message", self)
        self.send_button.setGeometry(220, 220, 200, 30)
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

        self.start_server()

        self.setWindowTitle("Server")

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.message_input.text()
        self.message_input.clear()
        self.client_socket.write(message.encode("utf-8"))


    def start_server(self):
        self.text_edit.clear()
        self.text_edit.append("Server started.")

    def handle_client_connection(self):
        self.client_socket = self.server.nextPendingConnection()
        self.client_socket.readyRead.connect(self.receive_message)

    def receive_message(self):
        client_socket = self.sender()
        data = client_socket.readAll().data().decode("utf-8")
        self.text_edit.append(f"Received message: {data}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

client.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSocket, QHostAddress

IP = '192.168.6.66'

class Client(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.client_socket = QTcpSocket(self)
        self.client_socket.readyRead.connect(self.receive_message)
        self.client_socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress(IP), 12345)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)

        self.message_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.message_input.setGeometry(10, 220, 200, 30)

        self.send_button = QPushButton("Send Message", self)
        self.send_button.setGeometry(220, 220, 200, 30)
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

        self.setWindowTitle("Client")

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.message_input.text()
        self.message_input.clear()
        self.client_socket.write(message.encode("utf-8"))

    def receive_message(self):
        data = self.client_socket.readAll().data().decode("utf-8")
        self.text_edit.append(f"Received message: {data}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client()
    client.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If the Python version works, why worry about the Qt version?  And where does `self.sender()` come from?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm just learning new things and wanted to know how that works. `self.sender()`  is used to retrieve the object that sent the signal to the connected slot. We could also use `self.client_socket` directly.

Comment: @Mohammad What does "failing" mean? Have you actually checked that the connections are made correctly? What does `server.listen(...)` return? And what is the output of `server.errorString()` and/or `client_socket.errorString()`? It might be a good idea to do some testing using one of the networking demos in the PyQt5 examples: e.g. see the [Fortune Server example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/network). (PS: the complete set of examples are included in the [PyQt5 source code](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files)).

Comment: @ekhumoro I was using some proxy on my computer. I disabled it and now it's working. I don't know why that should be a problem.